# Scala for comprehension - merging futures of AbstractSeq

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

having the following code:

```
def getListFull: Future[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] = {

  val windowSize = 8

  val result = for {
    response <- getResponse()
    if (response \ "response_code").extract[Int] == 0
    maxLine <- Future{(response \ "max_line").extract[Int]}
    res <- Future.traverse(0 until maxLine)(i => getResponse(..., i,...))
  } yield res

  Future.reduceLeft(result)(_ merge _)

  }
}
```

I get the following compile errors:

```
Error:(91, 48) Cannot construct a collection of type scala.collection.AbstractSeq[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] with elements of type org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue based on a collection of type scala.collection.AbstractSeq[Int].
    res <- Future.traverse(0 until maxLine)(i => getResponse(

Error:(91, 48) not enough arguments for method traverse: (implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.AbstractSeq[Int],org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue,scala.collection.AbstractSeq[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue]], implicit executor: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.AbstractSeq[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue]].
Unspecified value parameters cbf, executor.
    res <- Future.traverse(0 until maxLine)(i => getResponse(

Error:(98, 25) type mismatch;
found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing]
required: 
scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[scala.concurrent.Future[?]]
  Future.reduceLeft(result)(_ merge _)
```

The signature of the function getResponse is:

```
def getResponse(restUrl: String,
              urlParams: Map[String, String] = Map("" -> ""),
              connectTimeout: Int = 5000,
              readTimeout: Int = 5000,
              requestMethod: String = "GET"): Future[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] = Future {
```

The goal would be to call a REST API via **getResponse** multiple times with different arguments, and merge the resulting JSONs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `AbstractSeq` coming from and why not just use `Seq`? My Money is on the STL not providing an implicit `CanBuildFrom` for `AbstractSeq`, and it probably shouldn't if internals can be very different for the various implementors of `AbstractSeq`.

Comment: I don't konw, but if I replace the part '''(0 until maxLine)''' with ''''(0 to maxLine - 1)''', I get only this compile error:

Error:(100, 23) type mismatch;

 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.concurrent.Future[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue]]]

 required: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[scala.concurrent.Future[?]]
    Future.reduceLeft(result)(_ merge _)
Maybe this helps...

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] of your problem.